# Solution to Integral with "ln x" in exponent

Tags: integration

How would one solve the following equation?

\begin{equation}
 \int{x^{a \ln x + b}}dx
\end{equation}

Comment: Cannot be written in terms of elementary functions, I believe.  I'd _imagine_ it would use the imaginary error function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll skip the trivial case $a=0$. Substitute $u=\ln x$ so $$\int x^{a\ln x+b}dx=\int e^{a\ln^2 x+b\ln x}d(e^u)=\int e^{au^2+(b+1)u}du.$$You can do the rest with error functions (well, [imaginary error functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Imaginary_error_function) if $a>0$).

Comment: I should have seen that. u-substitution to the rescue again. Thank you